# Dependent project build breaks a WCF Service

Tags: .net, web-services, wcf

I have a WCF web service project, say FooService.vbproj with a FooService.svc endpoint.  Its implementation is in a separate project, Foo.vbproj, with a Foo.vb class that implements the IFooService service contract, and other files.  FooService has a project reference to Foo.  FooService is hosted in IIS locally.

When I build FooService, it compiles the Foo project, then the FooService project, and it **works just fine**; http://localhost/Foo/FooService.svc in a browser gives me the endpoint info page.  But then if I **build just Foo alone**, then I visit http://localhost/Foo/FooService.svc in a browser, I get a yellow screen of death, with "Method not found: 'Foo.Bar Foo.IFooService.GetFizz(System.Guid)'.  More details below.

Turns out it is copying an old version of Foo.dll into FooService's bin folder.  Where does that come from?

Any ideas on how to troubleshoot?  Shouldn't the service keep the "first" new Foo.dll so that the endpoint would still work?

Full stack trace:

```
[MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Foo.Bar Foo.IFooService.GetFizz(System.
       System.Reflection.Assembly._GetType(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase) +0
       System.Reflection.Assembly.GetType(String name, Boolean throwOnError) +36
       System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHostFactory.CreateServiceHost(String constructorString, Uri[] baseAddresses) +174
       MyCo.Infrastructure.MultipleBindingHostFactory.CreateServiceHost(String constructorString, Uri[] baseAddresses) +994
       System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.CreateService(String normalizedVirtualPath) +11666348
       System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.ActivateService(String normalizedVirtualPath) +42
       System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String normalizedVirtualPath) +479
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there was a circular indirect reference to Foo.dll in Foo through another reference.  Still not sure why it would copy a dll to a project not being built, though.

The important thing is that Visual Studio and/or msbuild behave unexpectedly when you have a circular reference.